# dbext not finding sql snippets to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, vim, vim-plugin, dbext

I'm trying to use the dbext vim plugin to connect to a MySQL database.

When I give commands like `<Leader>se` I get an error:

```
Can't open file 
/var/folders/b3/s3wyytf90_ld113h1w3p86ldcg4glv/T/vQ0XMX3/7
```

That file doesn't exist. But the SQL I expect to be executed does exist in:

```
/var/folders/b3/s3wyytf90_ld113h1w3p86ldcg4glv/T/vQ0XMX3/dbext.sql
```

So it looks as if the plugin is writing a temp file in one location and looking for it in another.

I'm sure the plugin can't be broken and I must have done something wrong, but I don't know enough Vimscript to follow it through.

I have `Vim v7.3, dbext 20.00` and have just installed by unzipping the plugin zip into my `.vim` directory.

I've used

`:DBPromptForBufferParameters`

to set up my connection parameters.

The full error looks like:

```
dbext: Executing SQL at 13:54
Error detected while processing function dbext#DB_execSql..dbext#DB_execFuncTypeWCheck..<SNR>42_DB_MYSQL_execSql..<SNR>42_DB_runCmd:
line   24:
E484: Can't open file /var/folders/b3/s3wyytf90_ld113h1w3p86ldcg4glv/T/v0BN3Qw/7
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this?

**Edit:** I've since tried an install into an empty .vim directory, with all of my other config and plugins removed, so I don't think that it's a case of conflicting configuration.

I'm running MacOSX, in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake on my part.

I was supplying a bare password which needed to be quoted in this context due to a special character.

I'm now quoting the password when prompted for it by `:DBPromptForBufferParameters` and everything is working.